# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined: directlink works but solution explorer file doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this error because VS can't find the jquery file. I have added it in solution explorer and added the source in my master page's head but VS can't find it for some unknown reason. I tried json2 and it doesn't work either. Finally I tried to use the directlink to jquery downloadpage and it worked and the problem was solved.

But, this isn't a clean fix since it will not work if the jquerysite stops working so I want a better fix do this problem. Do you have any tips?

This is the easy fix:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think jquery not included & it includes jquery its fine

Comment: Google also provide jquery cdn

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a jquery conflict error , please put this "jquery-1.9.1.min.js" file top of the all jquery files.

Comment: You can see if the page is loading jQuery at all by typing `$` in the developer console. If `$` is defined, your issue is probably related to load order.

Answer (score 0):

check your scripts folder

if you are using the same version of jquery as i am, you can add this line to your layout, if your page is indeed using a layout

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```